# Moving APIs efficiently

Tags: api, nginx

I currently have APIs running under http://example.com/api/v3/ and I want to move the APIs to a different server at http://exampleapi.com/v3.

I first thought about creating a location block in nginx to handle the requests such as:

```
location ~*/api/(v[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) {
    return 301 $scheme://exampleapi.com/$1;
}
```

However, using a REST client, the requests are being received as GET requests not POST. Same thing using a browser (Firefox).

I have tried the proxy pass but I was not able to make it work. This is what I tried:

```
location ~*/api/(v[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) {
    proxy_pass      http://exampleapi.com/$1;
    # proxy_redirect  http://exampleapi.com/ /;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

I am getting 502 or 500.

What is the best way to achieve moving the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging locally the same issue, I found out that I cannot proxy pass to a domain, but only to IP address as there is no resolver to resolve this domain.

Hence I created a new server block for exampleapi.com to listen on a port, and proxy passed to that port, such as:

```
 location ~*/api/(v[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:4545/$1;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```